# How to simply read tweets from any twitter user? (without loggin on twitter)

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to read tweets from a dinamically given twitter user in a Android app.

I found here (stackoverflow) and at google some ways to connect to twitter, but i didn't find a simply way to obtain the tweets of a given user without a loggin on twitter. I found some ways to do something similar with java, but using license protected librarys, and also i need to know the specific way with android (not java), **without** using license protected librarys.

There is a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother using libraries, just grab the data from the web.

- JSON: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=barackobama
- XML: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=barackobama

Just replace `screen_name` with any non-protected user and it'll work.

Comment: Above urls are giving only recent 15 tweets. Is there any way to get next 15 or even previous tweets also? Thanks.

Comment: @SANTHOSH Just add `&count=200`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I have to read 20 tweets on every call. How can I do so? Could you please tell me where is the API documentation on this?

Comment: Tried some trial & error method. Added &page=PAGE_NUM 
Got what exactly I wanted. Thanks bro.

Comment: Very old solution. now returns `The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active`

Answer (score 2):

Use Twitter4j library and the "Search for tweets" [example](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html).
You will not need to log in, just put the username whose tweets you want to read in the query and that's it.

Another way, if you dont want to use specific libraries, would be parsing the twitter page, with [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Parsing twitter.com pages isn't allowed by their ToS.